# In which city is Star Labs located?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe

In the DCEU in which city is the Star labs located. In the TV series *The Flash* it is located in the Central City but I want to know that in DCEU where is it located.

Comment: Your question is inaccurate.  There is no place in DC called the Central City.  In DC Comicis, movies, and televison, Central City is a place which has been in Ohio, Missouri, and Virginia at various times.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_City_(DC_Comics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's in Metropolis.

This is easily missed, because we barely see the actual [S.T.A.R. Labs](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.T.A.R._Labs) building in any of the DCEU films.

I should first clarify that the building shown at the beginning of the first two video clips (both from *[Justice League](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_(film))*) linked immediately below this paragraph is *not* S.T.A.R. Labs. It was a containment facility built around the [Kryptonian scout ship](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Scout_Ship_0344) that crashed in Metropolis in *[Man of Steel](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Man_of_Steel)*. The head of S.T.A.R. Labs, [Silas Stone](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Silas_Stone), is shown working at this facility in *Justice League*, but S.T.A.R. Labs itself is a separate building elsewhere in the city.

---

As far as I'm aware, the only time we're given an exterior shot of the actual S.T.A.R. Labs building in any of the films is during Superman's final fight with General Zod in Metropolis, near the end of *Man of Steel*. If you pause the video clip linked below at the 0:27 mark, you can see the building on the far right of the screen, with the red "S.T.A.R. Labs" logo running along the top. It's only a very brief shot though, and even paused, the logo is still a bit blurry because the camera is moving around in that shot.

Here's a screencap of the moment when the logo is most clearly visible:

[image: Screencap from the Man of Steel movie, showing the exterior of the S.T.A.R. Labs building on the far left of the image.]

There's also dialogue in *Justice League* indicating that six out of the first eight S.T.A.R. Labs staff members kidnapped by Darkseid's Parademons were taken from Metropolis (and the rest from Gotham, which is shown to be right across the bay from Metropolis in the DCEU):

> CRISPUS: **Eight kidnappings. Six in Metropolis, two here. All the vics work for S.T.A.R. Labs.**
>
> GORDON: "Attacked by a flying vampire." "Suspect was a giant bat with huge fangs."
>
> CRISPUS: One of them was a little kid. Scared. Won't say a word but drew this. Looks like...
>
> GORDON: I know what it looks like. Come on, you think he fights criminals for 20 years here and then he goes to Metropolis and kidnaps eight people? I'll talk to him tonight.
>
> CRISPUS: World's gone crazy, Jim. Maybe he did, too.

Dialogue in a later scene specifies that the eight staff members were kidnapped from or near S.T.A.R. Labs:

> GORDON: How many of you are there?
>
> BATMAN: Not enough.
>
> GORDON: **Eight people abducted from or near S.T.A.R. Labs.** Here's the potential perp.
>
> WONDER WOMAN: Parademons.
>
> FLASH: Okay.
>
> WONDER WOMAN: The demons must have caught the scent of the Mother Box. They carried people away to find out what they know.
>
> BATMAN:  So the eight may still be alive.
>
> CYBORG: Nine.
>
> (FLASH GASPS)
>
> CYBORG: The head of S.T.A.R. Labs was taken as well.
>
> WONDER WOMAN: You made it. So then, there must be a nest nearby.
>
> GORDON: I plotted all the sightings in Metropolis, Gotham. No pattern I can see. The lines on the map don't converge.
>
> CYBORG: On land. These lead back to Braxton Island, between the two cities.
>
> BATMAN: Gotham Harbor. These are air vents. They all lead down to the tunnel to the Metropolis Project that was abandoned in '29.
>
> GORDON: Do you really think that...
>
> FLASH: Oh, wow. They just... They really just vanish. Huh? Oh. That's rude.

We get an interior shot of the building in the brief clip of Cyborg's origin shown in *[Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice)*, but that doesn't give anything away about which city the building is located in.

Comment: I've always said since Force Awakens if JJ made a Pearl Harbor film he'd have kids in Boston seeing a wisp of smoke on the western horizon and running to tell their moms- who gasp in horror because the base in Hawaii got bombed